# Is there a node/npm equivalent for Ruby's `bundle open #{gem_name}`?

Tags: ruby, node.js, npm, bundler

`bundle open #{gem_name}` opens a gem you have installed in the application specified by `BUNDLER_EDITOR` or `EDITOR` if the former is not present.

Obviously it is possible to open the actual location instead, I'm just wondering if node/npm have a similar helper feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`npm edit <pkg>`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/edit) command to do this

> #### Description
>
> Opens the package folder in the default editor (or whatever you've configured as the npm editor config -- see `npm-config`.)
>
> After it has been edited, the package is rebuilt so as to pick up any changes in compiled packages.
>
> For instance, you can do `npm install connect` to install connect into your package, and then `npm edit connect` to make a few changes to your locally installed copy.
>
> #### Configuration
>
> **editor**
>
> - Default: **EDITOR** environment variable if set, or "**vi**" on Posix, or "**notepad**" on Windows.
> - Type: path
>
> The command to run for `npm edit` or `npm config edit`.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for. Though I would never guessed `edit` :P.